# Fancybox not working with HTML/java Driven Content

Tags: java, html, ajax, fancybox

I have a problem that has been bugging me for around 2 days now and seem to be getting low responses elsewhere. I am running XML's that string along the data into AJAX tabs.

then using Javascript, to break and only display the XML data where I want, then I want some of the data to appear through a Lightbox  which and not on the AJAX tab through the 'read more' hyperlink.

Some of the data appears normally however the Lightbox is not working at all, the scripts are loaded and linked correctly but I cannot seem to work out why it is not working. Each Lightbox has been generated through the script and yet, no Lightbox or linking is working correctly.

Because some Lightbox's work using similar things as div anchors, it seems to be anchoring instead.

For a live version see:

http://universitycompare.com/university-guide/london-metropolitan-university/

alternatively, the script I have done is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://universitycompare.com/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/XML/<?php echo the_field('university_xml_courses'); ?>",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

document.write("<table border='0'>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("KISCOURSE");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)

  { 
  document.write("<tr id='CourseArea'><td><h3 id='CourseTitle'>");

  // TITLE
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</h3>");
  document.write("<p class='ForP'>-&nbsp;&nbsp;");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("MODE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue); 
  document.write("</p><div class='clear'></div>");

  // UCAS CODE
  document.write("<p id='ucascode'>");
  document.write("<b>UCAS CODE</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("UCASCOURSEID")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</p>"); 

  // READ MORE LIGHTBOX
  document.write("<img src='http://universitycompare.com/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/images/info-icon.png' width='15' style='margin:0px 2px 0px -4px;'>");
  document.write("<a id='various' href='#inline'>Read More</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");

  // VISIT COURSE LINK
  document.write("<a class='courselink' href='");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("CRSEURL")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("' target='_blank'>Visit course website</a>");
  document.write("</td></tr>");

  // LIGHTBOX INFO
  document.write("<div class='inline' style='display:none; width:500px; height:500px;'>"); 
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("CRSEURL")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue); 
  document.write("</div>");
  }

document.write("</table>");

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell you are binding fancybox to the selector `.various` (an element with `class="various"`) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".various").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
});
```

... however there isn't t any element in your content with such *class* but

```
<a id='various' href='#inline'>Read More</a>
```

maybe you meant

```
<a class='various' href='#inline'>Read More</a>
```

**Additional recommendations** : fix some of your html syntax inconsistencies like

- your `<head>` opening tag is missing.
- place all your scripts either inside your `<head>` or `<body>` sections, but not in between ... this:

  ```
  <head>
  .
  </head>
  <script> ....</script>
  <body>
  .
  </body>
  ```

  ... is not recommended
- other javascript errors may affect the behavior of your other jQuery plugins. Your page throws this js error:

  ```
  Timestamp: 06/10/2012 5:48:24 PM
  Error: TypeError: $(this).get(0) is undefined
  Source File: http://universitycompare.com/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/jquery.ticker.js
  Line: 25
  ```

Comment: began making these changes, and still nothing, could it be a problem that where they are all generated that the lightbox won't work as they all will have the same div id - if that makes sense? How would I go about making it so it will regenerate a new div'id for each one?